# error while sending files into aws s3 - react - react-aws-s3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

my problem is that I have strange response on put operation into my bucket
Im using package react-aws-s3, in the configuration it only requires the name of the bucket, user keys, and region, so it's hard to get something broken on the code side.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i already have this setup and still the same issue :c
https://imgur.com/a/StuhVWF

Answer (score 0):

if CORS is already enabled , please check below points, also did you included PUT verb as part of request method..

1. The request's Origin header must match AllowedOrigin elements.
2. The request method (for example, GET, PUT, HEAD, and so on) or the
   Access-Control-Request-Method header in case of a pre-flight OPTIONS
   request must be one of the AllowedMethod elements.
3. Every header specified in the Access-Control-Request-Headers request
   header of a pre-flight request must match an AllowedHeader element.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oddmwLl im allowing everything for everyone, and still doesn't work

Comment: instead of POST could you please try with PUT.

refer below doc. [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.htm)